# Removing words featured in character vector from string

Tags: r

I have a character vector of stopwords in R:

```
stopwords = c("a" ,
            "able" ,
            "about" ,
            "above" ,
            "abst" ,
            "accordance" ,
            ...
            "yourself" ,
            "yourselves" ,
            "you've" ,
            "z" ,
            "zero")
```

Let's say I have the string:

`str <- c("I have zero a accordance")`

How can remove my defined stopwords from `str`?

I think `gsub` or another `grep` tool could be a good candidate to pull this off, although other recommendations are welcome.

Comment: You can try `gsub(paste(stopwords, collapse="|"), "", str)`

Comment: @akrun better `gsub(paste0("\\b(",paste(stopwords, collapse="|"),")\\b"), "", str)`, otherwise every `a` will be deleted.

Comment: @nicola Yes, that is better.  I didn't test it before.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the [`tm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) library for this:

```
require("tm")
removeWords(str,stopwords)
#[1] "I have   "
```

Comment: I think this is a thorough answer. Other current answers rely too heavily on space delimiters, but there are other characters that represent word boundaries. For example, in the string `"I have zero a accordance, you've not been yourself."` this answer performs well. Of course you could remove those boundary characters beforehand, but `tm` has other useful functions like `removePunctuation`.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
str <- c("I have zero a accordance")

stopwords = c("a", "able", "about", "above", "abst", "accordance", "yourself",
"yourselves", "you've", "z", "zero")

x <- unlist(strsplit(str, " "))

x <- x[!x %in% stopwords]

paste(x, collapse = " ")

# [1] "I have"
```

**Addition:** Writing a "removeWords" function is simple so it is not necessary to load an external package for this purpose:

```
removeWords <- function(str, stopwords) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(str, " "))
  paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
}

removeWords(str, stopwords)
# [1] "I have"
```

Comment: I find this way better than the implemented function in the tm package, because the latter has size limits. I work with a corpus of forum comments and wanted to remove all the usernames from the text (around 70000). I kept getting an error from R, because the regex was too large. Thank you!

Comment: This solution is way faster than the `tm`package! Thanks for sharing!!

Comment: Note that this is case-sensitive, so blacklisted words starting a sentence (for example) will not be removed. It also splits by spaces, so blacklisted words next to any punctuation won't be removed either. Whether this is a big deal or not depends on your purposes.

For the first issue, either change line 2 to `x <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(str, " ")))` to make everything lower-case to match the stopword list (if preserving capitalisation is not important), or duplicate the stopword list to have a copy of each word starting with a capital letter (if capitalisation is important).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for a function if you want the code to be vectorized for many sentences, not just one. It borrows content from Mikko's original answer.

```
remove_words <- function(str, words) {
      
  purrr::map_chr(
    str, 
    function(sentence) {
      sentence_split <- unlist(strsplit(sentence, " "))
      paste(sentence_split[!sentence_split %in% words], collapse = " ")
    }
  )
      
}
    
remove_words(c('Hello world', 'This is another sentence', 'Test sentence 3'), c('world', 'sentence'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the comment from @nikola you could do (this does not scale well):

```r
str <- "I have zero a accordance"
stopwords <-  c("a", "able", "about", "above", "abst", "accordance", "yourself",
                "yourselves", "you've", "z", "zero")

gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", str)
# [1] "I have   "
```

You can clean up the extra space using `trimws`:

```r
trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", str))
# [1] "I have"
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, some other answers rely on words being delimited by a space and do not work well here:

```r
str <- "I have zero a accordance, you've not been yourself."

removeWords(str, stopwords) # @Mikko
[1] "I have accordance, not been yourself."

gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", str)
# [1] "I have   ,  not been ."

tm::removeWords(str,stopwords)
# [1] "I have   ,  not been ."
```

#### Benchmark

- `tm::removeWords` is the fastest at this time

A really long string:

```r
x <- "I have zero a accordance"

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  removeWords = removeWords(str, stopwords),
  tm_removeWords = tm::removeWords(str, stopwords),
  gsub = gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", str),
  unit = "relative",
  setup = {str <- paste(rep(x, 1E3), collapse = " ")}
)
Unit: relative
           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
    removeWords  3.515652  3.348684  3.316332  3.357253  3.283062  2.961932   100 a  
 tm_removeWords  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100  b 
           gsub 49.544363 46.691421 45.235146 46.332785 44.683394 35.688565   100   c
```

Many strings:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  removeWords = removeWords(str, stopwords),
  tm_removeWords = tm::removeWords(str, stopwords),
  gsub = gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", str),
  unit = "relative",
  setup = {str <- rep(x, 1E3)}
)
Unit: relative
           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
    removeWords  2.755229  2.722939  2.682882  2.640442  2.690049  2.612228   100 a  
 tm_removeWords  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100  b 
           gsub 39.934159 38.408355 37.122552 37.703357 36.852635 31.263544   100   c
```