# R: removing part of the word in a character string

Tags: r, regex, gsub, tm, stringr

I have a character vector

```
words <- c("somethingspan.", "..span?", "spanthank", "great to hear", "yourspan")
```

And I'm trying to remove `span` AND punctuation from every word in the vector

```
> something thank great to hear your
```

The thing is, there's no rule if `span` will appear before or after the word I'm interested in. Also, `span` can be glued to: i) characters only (e.g. `yourspan`), punctuation only (e.g. `..span?`) or character and punctuation (e.g.  `somethingspan.`).

I searched SO for the answer, but usually I see request to remove whole words (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790652/removing-words-featured-in-character-vector-from-string) ) or elements of the string after/before a letter/punctuation (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704213/r-remove-part-of-string) )

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please share the code that fails.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 That `gsub("span", "", words)` will only remove `span`, but will keep the `.` in `somethingspan.`. The question is unclear.

Comment: `gsub("span[[:punct:]]*", "", words)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj *combination of the two*.

Comment: What do you mean by *it can be followed by characters, punctuation, combination of the two, etc.*? Are "characters" letters? What "combination" are you talking about? Please provide more examples with exact expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited my question, hope it's clear(er) now, let me know if not

Comment: Try `paste(gsub("[[:punct:]]*span[[:punct:]]*", "", words), collapse=" ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[[:punct:]]*span[[:punct:]]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxfctJ/1).

**Details**

- `[[:punct:]]*` - 0+ punctuations chars
- `span` - a literal substring
- `[[:punct:]]*` - 0+ punctuations chars

[R Demo](https://ideone.com/iz5wN3):

```
words <- c("somethingspan.", "..span?", "spanthank", "great to hear", "yourspan")
words <- gsub("[[:punct:]]*span[[:punct:]]*", "", words) # Remove spans
words <- words[words != ""] # Discard empty elements
paste(words, collapse=" ")  # Concat the elements
## => [1] "something thank great to hear your"
```

If there result whitespace only elements after removing unwanted strings, you may replace the second step with `words <- words[trimws(words) != ""]` (instead of `words[words != ""]`).

Answer (score 2):

https://regex101.com/ here you can try everything.

```
clean_words<- gsub(pattern = "span",replacement = "",words, perl = T)
# if you want the sentence
sentence<-paste(clean_words, sep = " ", collapse = " ")

# to remove punctuation this regex only takes from A to z
clean_sentence<- gsub(pattern = "[^a-zA-Z ]",replacement = "",sentence, perl = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub` to remove span. To make it into a sentence use `paste` and `collapse`

```
library(magrittr)

sub("^[[:punct:]]{,2}span|span[[:punct:]]{,2}$", "", words)  %>% paste(collapse=" ")
```

so it only removes a span in the beginning or in the end.

#### Output

```
[1] "something ? thank great to hear your"
```

Comment: `"^span|span$"` will not handle `"somethingspan."`, there is a `.` at the end. See OP: *it can be followed by characters, punctuation, combination of the two, etc.*. So, even `[[:punct:]]?` before `$` won't help. The question is unclear.

Comment: Andre, the question is too unclear, but have a look at *it can be followed by characters, punctuation, combination of the two, etc.* Just `[[:punct:]]?` won't help.

Comment: @Wiktor, what's unclear about the question? I'll clarify it

Comment: Yes its unclear. I guess the code provided by all of us. Should lead @Kasia to her goal.

Comment: @Kasia, please have ALL possibilities that can occur in your rep. code.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I provided a dummy example of my data and a desirable output. This should answer all your questions above