# Removing multiple words from a string using a vector instead of regexp in R

Tags: r, string, vector, stringr

I would like to remove multiple words from a string in R, but would like to use a character vector instead of a regexp.

For example, if I had the string

```
"hello how are you"
```

and wanted to remove

```
c("hello", "how")
```

I would return

```
" are you"
```

I can get close with `str_remove()` from `stringr`

```
"hello how are you" %>% str_remove(c("hello","how"))
[1]  "how are you"   "hello  are you"
```

But I'd need to do something to get this down into a single string. Is there a function that does all of this on one call?

Comment: Related: [Removing words featured in character vector from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790652/removing-words-featured-in-character-vector-from-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `|` to evaluate as a regex OR

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
pat <- str_c(words, collapse="|")
"hello how are you" %>% 
      str_remove_all(pat) %>%
      trimws
#[1] "are you"
```

#### data

```
words <- c("hello", "how")
```

Comment: Improvement suggestion: paste+collapse = "|" on a vector of words.. so you don't have to retype everyting?

Comment: Great idea -- very clever! I am surprised that something like this isn't implemented in one of the strings packages, but this is a simple workaround.

Comment: For `str_remove` the default interpretation is `regex`.  You can wrap with `fixed` though.  But, the issue is that it expects the pattern and string to be of same length.  `"hello how are you" %>%  str_remove_all(fixed(words))
[1] " how are you"   "hello  are you"`

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` possibility could be:

```
x <- "hello how are you"   
trimws(gsub("hello|how", "\\1", x))

[1] "are you"
```

Or if you have more words, a clever idea proposed by @Wimpel:

```
words <- paste(c("hello", "how"), collapse = "|")
trimws(gsub(words, "\\1", x))
```